# How to pass Java opts in keycloak application, I want to pass java agent to java opts along with current java opts

Tags: java, microservices, keycloak, keycloak-services

How to pass Java opts in keycloak application, I want to pass java agent to java opts along with current java opts ?

We tried to pass java_opts in standalone.sh and standalone.conf files but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have use environment `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND: "-Dkeycloak.client.searchableAttributes=attrA"` with keycloak docker, and it worked. I thought you should use envrionemnt `JAVA_OPTS_APPEND`, as it mentioned here: [Configure Keycloak Server with IPv6 or IPv4](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration-production#_configure_keycloak_server_with_ipv6_or_ipv4)